# Grep 3 Capital Letters and Digits into Two Variables

Tags: bash, grep

I've created a script that uses a `for loop` to loop through an IBM script to get the size of directories. The script then outputs the directory size and path
to a Slack channel for easy viewing. The program works but the output of the IBM script is large and needs formatting to make it easy to read in Slack. So
I need to collect two pieces of information which will be piped into two separate variables with the variables being used to create the Slack message.
My script looks like:

```
SIZE () {
  for dir in /path/to/dir/*
  do
    cd /usr/lpp/mmfs/samples/ilm/
    SLACKMESSAGE=$(./mmpolicy-du.sample "$dir" -t /mmfs1/.policytmp -g /mmfs1/.policytmp/ -N all -v -h)
    SLACK
  done
}
```

So `/path/to/dir/*` is the parent directory and the IBM script `./mmpolicy-du.sample "$dir" -t /mmfs1/.policytmp -g /mmfs1/.policytmp/ -N all -v -h`
will loop through all the child direcotries (one level deep) and get their size. The output looks like:

```
[I] 2018-05-31@16:32:55.798 Policy execution. 0 files dispatched.
[I] 2018-05-31@16:32:55.804 Policy execution. 0 files dispatched.
File system scan complete.
534.5M     total
mmapplypolicy du for /path/to/directory/SPI/ complete at Thu May 31 17:32:55 2018
```

That's not the cleanest output so I'd like to pipe the directory size in the above example case `534.5M` into a variable called `SIZE` and the `SPI` into another variable called `PROJECT`. Of course being a loop the `SIZE` and `PROJECT` variable will change on each directory inside the above example of `/path/to/dir/`. The Slack function which gets called in my above function will use those two variables.
I'm struggling to work out how to get those two into variables. 
Anyone have a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Show us an example input and a desired output.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: I think this is still unclear.  It may be better to explain what your end goal is. You say this program will have lots of output and you want to assign **A** variable for each.  Do you need a new variable for each or reuse the same one to perform a task?  How do you want to accomplish this?  With a script that wraps around your program or are you expecting to just run the program through a pipeline?

Comment: @Dani_l Yes Sorry I meant `PROJECT` as the variable. Question edited.

Comment: Some sample data here (input and desired output) would be _really useful_.

Comment: @roaima so in my above example I have a directory which is full of other directories. I want to loop through all the directories inside the parent directory to get their size using an IBM script rather than `du`. In my question you can see the output is rather messy so I want to clean it by finding each directory name and size and size and then output them into two variables which are used in a Slack message so I can see the size of the directories. So an output should show something like `SIZE=2TB` and `PROJECTED=SPI` which will be seen in a Slack channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it in one go:

```
eval "$(yourscript | awk -v q=\' '
  $1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?[MGT]$/ {
    print "SIZE=" $1
  }
  match($0, /[[:upper:]]{3}/) {
    print "PROJECT="q substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) q
  }')"
```

Note that some `awk` implementations like the `nawk` or Solaris, `mawk` or older versions of `gawk` don't support the `{x,y}`/`{x}` regular expression interval operators (in the case of older (and not ancient) versions of `gawk`, you can run it with `POSIXLY_CORRECT=anything` in the environment for it to support them though) even though it has been standard for over 25 years now. With those, you would need to replace `[[:upper:]]{3}` with `[[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:upper:]]`.

Comment: I like this @StéphaneChazelas. I edited my function but when I ran it the size was returned but not the 3 capital letters.

Comment: @sark, possibly your awk is one of those implementations that don't support interval RE operators. Try replacing `[[:upper:]]{3}` with `[[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:upper:]]`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much this is what you need, but this answers you current question verbatim.

First part (assuming GNU `grep` or compatible):

```
project="$(yourscript|grep -oE '[[:upper:]]{3}')"
```

Second part:

```
size="$(yourscript|grep -oE '[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?[MGT]')"
```

Combined it's simpler to run the script once, save the output and grep and assign on the saved output:

```
output="$(script)"
size="$(printf '%s\n' "$output"|grep -oE '[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?[MGT]')"
project="$(printf '%s\n' "$output"|grep -oE '[[:upper:]]{3}')"
```

Some explanation
`grep -o` - only return the object grepped, not the entire line
`-E` - Extended regex
`[[:upper:]]` - match uppercase letters only ([A-Z], but regardless of locale)
`{3}` - limit the match to exactly 3 consecutive chars.
`[[:digit:]]` - match digits ([0-9], again w/o regard to locale)
`+` - match 1 or more times
`\.` - match a dot
`(...)?` - match 0 or 1 times - this ensures numbers without a decimal dot might also be captured
`[xy]` - matched exactly one of the items x or y.

Comment: @Jesse_b thx, corrected

Comment: And quote the shell globs and avoid echo for arbitrary data. `[x|y]` matches on `x`, `|` or `y`. You need `[xy]` for either `x` or `y`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas can you show what you mean ? I'm not sure what the problem with echo or current quoting is

Comment: See edit and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you, it's much clearer now.